# Duplicate pageItem from one layer to another in illustrator without offset

Tags: adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm copying items from a layer in one illustrator document into a new layer in a new illustrator document. It all works fine except that the items do not 'paste' into the same location in the new illustrator document. They are in a different position on the artboard to the original. Could anyone tell me how to resolve this, I've had a good look around but can't find anything.

Many thanks

```
var targetLayer = newDoc.layers.add()
    for (var k = 0; k < layerName.pageItems.length; k++) {
        var newItem = layerName.pageItems[k].duplicate(targetLayer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATEND)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
for (var k = 0; k < layerName.pageItems.length; k++) {
        var pos = layerName.pageItems[k].position
        var newItem = layerName.pageItems[k].duplicate(targetLayer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATEND)
        newItem.position = pos
    }
```